How to Configure Cloudflare Zaraz for Multiple Subdomains and Production Websites?
I am setting up Cloudflare Zaraz for a project that requires deploying across multiple subdomains and distinct production environments. I am looking for guidance on best practices and configuration tips specific to Cloudflare Zaraz to ensure a smooth setup.
Here are my specific questions:
Subdomain Setup: How should I configure Zaraz to effectively manage multiple subdomains? Are there particular settings or approaches recommended for handling traffic and tools across these subdomains?
Environment Segregation: What is the best way to separate production, staging, and development environments within Zaraz? Are there specific configurations or practices that help maintain these environments cleanly and securely?
Analytics and Tools Management: How can Zaraz be used to manage different analytics or marketing tools across these environments and subdomains? Is there a way to customize tool activation based on the domain or environment?
Performance Considerations: Are there any implications for performance when using Zaraz in a complex setup with multiple subdomains and environments? How can I ensure optimal performance?
Any insights, examples, or resources you could share would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Subdomain Setup
Zaraz is a zone-level Cloudflare resource. This means that it is configured and applied across a zone. Zones in Cloudflare are APEX domains which means that foo.example.com, bar.example.com, and example.com are all under the same zone and thus share the same Zaraz configuration.
Environment Segregation
Zaraz has what they call Preview & Publish Mode which allows you to version control and preview changes to your Zaraz configuration before going live. Since Zaraz deals with marketing and analytics tools, you typically do not want it running in your staging or development; however, if you load Zaraz (either by letting Cloudflare add it) or if you manually load Zaraz, you'll be able to use it in any environment you like.
Analytics and Tools Management
There are two ways to do this. First, you can use Configuration Rules to load Zaraz selectively across your different subdomains and environments. This lets you not load Zaraz on foo.example.com while keeping it active on bar.example.com. The next level down would be only loading certain tools on certain sites. As previously mentioned, Zaraz is a zone-level resource, which means the configuration is done at a zone level. If you want to run different tools on different subdomains within the same zone, you will need to do some advanced configuration methods. The most straightforward of these methods would be what Zaraz calls a Blocking Trigger. This is a normal Zaraz trigger, but when configuring an action, you tell Zaraz not to fire if this trigger is fired, even if the action is triggered. If you create a trigger that fires on a certain subdomain this would allow you to fairly easily prevent tools from firing on subdomains where you do not want them to.
Performance Considerations
There are two types of performance in this case:

Page load: This is impacted by things preventing your page from loading. Configuration rules would potentially impact this, but the effect should be negligible.
Zaraz processing: The more complex the triggers and actions you create, the more processing Zaraz has to do. Most of this is handled on the server within Zaraz's internals, but a really complex setup would probably add a slight delay in sending data to your analytics providers, but again this should be negligible.

The key here is that a complex Zaraz setup should have minimal to no impact on your actual page speed. Even if, to exaggerate, something you did increased the time it took to send an analytics event by an extra second, this isn't going to matter unless your use case requires sub-second real-time analytics because it's offloaded to Zaraz, and your website user's experience is not impacted. In practice, any potential delay is likely to be much shorter, only adding a few milliseconds, and those few milliseconds are not being waited on by your users; instead, it just means that your analytics partner is getting data a tiny bit slower.
Hope this helps!
